# Почему блок располагается с огромным отступом?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

**Вопрос:** Почему блок `.break` расположен от блока `h1` с огромным отступом в `440px`?
Я нигде этого в коде не указывал.
Как это исправить?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: rgba(47, 60, 255, 0.49);
}

.container {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1600px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #303f62;
  height: calc(100vh - 150px);
  min-height: 1100px;
  width: 100%;
}

.content-wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: #e3ffa2;
  width: 80%;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80%;
  margin-top: 50px;
  background: red;
}

h1 {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto 30px auto;
}

.break {
  height: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content-wrap">
      <div class="content">
        <h1>О нас</h1>
        <div class="break"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="break"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас для элемента `.content` указано в стилях `display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;`
А `align-content` не указано. По дефолту оно принимает значение `align-content: stretch;`
Отсюда и такой эффект. Поставьте `align-content: flex-start;`, это решит проблему.

**Пример с `align-content: stretch;`**

```css
.container {
  background-color: tomato;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  
  height: 500px;
}

.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

**Пример с `align-content: flex-start;`**

```css
.container {
  background-color: tomato;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  
  align-content: flex-start;
  
  height: 500px;
}

.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Ваш пример:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: rgba(47, 60, 255, 0.49);
}

.container {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1600px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #303f62;
  height: calc(100vh - 150px);
  min-height: 1100px;
  width: 100%;
}

.content-wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: flex-start; /* добавил */
  
  background: #e3ffa2;
  width: 80%;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: flex-start; /* добавил */
  
  width: 100%;
  height: 80%;
  margin-top: 50px;
  background: red;
}

h1 {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto 30px auto;
}

.break {
  height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  
  border-bottom: 10px solid rgba(47, 60, 255, 1); /* просто выделил */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content-wrap">
      <div class="content">
        <h1>О нас</h1>
        <div class="break"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="break"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Потому-что у вас блоку .content задана высота 80%, а h1 находится в нем. Т.е. по сути оступ идет от блока content